# is it possible to use node bacnet stack in an ionic cordova application

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, bacnet

I want to develop an android & ios application that communicates over wifi network with a bacnet device.
for that how can i make use of [node-bacstack](https://github.com/fh1ch/node-bacstack) , ionic, cordova.

I've seen most use-cases of [node-bacstack](https://github.com/fh1ch/node-bacstack) follow the following architecture

[image]

as mentioned in the above image **bacstack** resides on the server-side.

In my use-case there is no server, so how can I use [node-bacstack](https://github.com/fh1ch/node-bacstack) to develop the ionic Cordova app that communicates over wifi network with a bacnet device. Is it possible?

Any suggestions are welcomed!